# LDAP and Persistence Data?

Tags: ldap, persistence, persistent-storage

I was just curious why an LDAP (Lightweight Directory Protocol) would or would not be considered persistence data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up a "protocol" with "data". There is no "LDAP data".

Apart from that, an LDAP directory can be seen as a classical example of persistent storage.

1. LDAP directory entries have an average lifetime in the range of weeks, or even months.
2. LDAP servers are optimized for an "occasional writes, many reads" usage pattern.
3. Modern LDAP servers allow mechanisms for ensuring data consistency in the directory.